# Unserialize function doesn't return array values

Tags: php

Hello i want to unserialize an array in order to display the array values.
The way that the array is inserted to my db field is like this.

```
persons: "a:1:{i:0;s:55:"[{"value":"john: writer"},{"value":"john: producer"}]";}"
```

and the function i have done but i am not getting any results is this

```
$adDetails = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($adDetails as $feed) {
    $feed->logo_pic = SITE_URL . $feed->logo_pic;
    $feed->image_path = SITE_URL . $feed->image_path;
    $feed->media_pic = SITE_URL . 'mediaPic/' . $feed->media_pic;

    $personsArr = unserialize(array($feed->persons));
    $personsText = " ";
    if(!empty($personsArr)){
        list($firstItem) = $personsArr;
        foreach ($firstItem as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($value as $valueInner) {
                $personsText .= $valueInner.", ";
            }
        } 
    }
    $feed->personsNew = $personsText; 
}
$response['success'] = true;
$response['adDetails'] = $adDetails;
echo json_encode($response);
```

I am getting nothing on personsText although persons is  persons: "a:1:{i:0;s:55:"[{"value":"john: writer"},{"value":"john: producer"}]";}"

Any help?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the serialized data, the string is only 53 characters long but it has `s:55`.

Comment: yes it should look like this right? a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:5:"value";s:6:"WRITER";}i:1;a:1:{s:5:"value";s:7:"FHFHFHF";}}}

Answer (score 0):

The value in the array is a JSON string, so you need to decode it.

The argument to `unserialize()` should just be `$feed->persons`, it shouldn't be in an array.

Instead of the loop, you can use `array_column()` to get all the `value` elements, and `implode()` to combine them with comma delimiters.

```
$adDetails = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($adDetails as $feed) {
    $feed->logo_pic = SITE_URL . $feed->logo_pic;
    $feed->image_path = SITE_URL . $feed->image_path;
    $feed->media_pic = SITE_URL . 'mediaPic/' . $feed->media_pic;

    $personsArr = unserialize($feed->persons);
    $personsText = " ";
    if(!empty($personsArr)){
        $firstItem = json_decode($personsArr[0], true);
        $personsText = implode(', ', array_column($firstItem, 'value'));
    }
    $feed->personsNew = $personsText; 
}
$response['success'] = true;
$response['adDetails'] = $adDetails;
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: no doesn't work. updated with photo to see

Comment: `unserialize` takes a string not an array.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Good eye.

Comment: it is a string because i send it like this in the API  anArray: JSON.stringify(this.anArray)

Comment: You could decode it before you serialize it and store in the DB, then you wouldn't need to unserialize and deccode after fetching.

Comment: If you're doing `serialize(array($_POST['parametername']))` you can do `serialize(array(json_decode($_POST['parametername'], true)))`. Also, why are you putting it in an array if there's just one element?